# Stylesheet Pseudo-State Syntax in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I have various PushButtons roaming about my script, and I'm loading in an external css file to handle the mass of widgets in my software. I'm getting to the point where I'm having to hunt down buttons by class and trying to define certain properties. The generic call to a button, like: QFrame:QPushButton #btnName { css: blah; } is working, however the pseudo-states are not: specifically hover and pressed. Here's what i'm trying:

```
--THIS WORKS
QFrame:QPushButton #btnName { css: blah; }

--THESE DO NOT
QFrame:QPushButton:hover #btnName { css: hoverstuff; }
QFrame:QPushButton:pressed #btnName { css: pressedstuff; }
```

There are plenty of css stylings in the sheet; could it be a matter of what's 'above' these lines? Is my syntax wrong for the pseudo-states? What gives!? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is interesting. That syntax is not working for me. Are you sure it is working there? Actually, it should be `QFrame QPushButton#btnName`. Mind the spaces and missing colon. And for pseudo states you should do `QFrame QPushButton#btnName:hover`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current syntax you are using is wrong in all your examples.

The selector `QFrame:QPushButton` will simply ignore `:QPushbutton` because it is not a valid [pseudo-state](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states). Also, the space before the ID Selector means that the rule will apply to *all* descendant objects called `#btnName` (which is probably not what you intended, but is why the first example sort of works anyway).

I assume what you really wanted was for the rule to apply to any `QPushButton` with an `objectName` of "btnName", which is also a descendant of a `QFrame`.

In which case, the first rule should be:

```
QFrame QPushButton#btnName { css: blah; }
```

and the other two rules should be:

```
QFrame QPushButton#btnName:hover { css: hoverstuff; }
QFrame QPushButton#btnName:pressed { css: pressedstuff; }
```

See [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) for further details on Selector Types.

Comment: Personal savior as always, ekhu. Thanks!